# Is it possible/safe to call AWS Lambda function directly from frontend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have Lambda function that executes in minimum 12 seconds so I can't expose it via AWS API Gateway (because of 10 sec timeout). What I was thinking is to call/execute Lambda function directly from frontend through AWS javascript SDK. Is it safe to create IAM user that will have only permission to execute this one particular function and hardcode this user AWS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_KEY in frontend?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is possible. 
New [AWS Service Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) allows you to provide AWS creds specific to the end user. You can use those creds to access different aws services like `DynamoDB` or in your case `AWS Lambda`.

> Is it safe to create IAM user that will have only permission to
>   execute this one particular function and hardcode this user AWS_KEY_ID
>   and AWS_SECRET_KEY in frontend?

Never do do this. Use [AWS Service Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) instead.

Comment: Would you have any reference on why this solution is more safe?

Comment: Hmm now I realized that I don't understand how I can use Cognito here. I thought it's for authenticating mobile users. I just want to make it possible to call Lambda function from frontend by any anonymous user that visits the page. I don't even want to authenticate/authorize any users. How I can use Cognito in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Amazon Gateway API's to connect from so called "front end" to lambda, checkout [this tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html) from amazon.

Answer (score 0):

You can build RESTful services with aws API Gateway and Lambda. Build your Lambda functions using blueprint "microservice-http-endpoint" or manually point your API end points to already created Lambda functions. [This tutorial](http://www.texient.com/2016/02/java-building-restful-microservices-with-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway.html) explains how to build a REST service using API Gateway, Lambda and DynamoDB.

You may face challenges if you are doing the domain mapping and error mapping manually, aws provides an option to build endpoints from swagger documentation. Once imported, you can map your Lambda functions to each endpoint manually.